# Preimage of compact set

Tags: general-topology

If $f: X \rightarrow Y$ is continuous. $B \subseteq Y$ is compact, and $A \subseteq B$ is also compact. If we know $f^{-1}(B)$ is compact in $X$, does it tell us anything about whether $f^{-1}(A)$ is compact in $X$?

I think if we reverse the contained, the statement might be true. Have been thinking about this for a while, but can not think of anyway to prove or disprove this. Any help would be appreciated!

Edit: We do not assume Hausdorff or anything else about $X$ or $Y$.

Comment: Do you have any hypothesis about $X$ or $Y$ (like been Hausdorff spaces)?

Comment: Sorry I do not know how to reply to comment, but no, we do not assume anything of $X$ or $Y$. Already edited the problem. @jjagmath

Comment: If $Y$ is Hausdorff, then $A$ is closed, so $f^{-1}[A]$ is a closed subset of $f^{-1}[B]$ and is therefore compact. If $Y$ is not Hausdorff, $A$ need not be closed, and $f^{-1}[A]$ need not be compact: see **Rod H**’s answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not necessarily. Here’s a possible counterexample.
Let $X=[-1,1],\ \tau_X$ be standard Euclidean topology, $Y=\{a,b\}$, $\tau_Y=\{\{a\},Y,\varnothing \}.$ $f([-1,1))=a$, $f(1)=b$. Now let $B=Y,\ A=\{a\}.$ The point is compactness does not always imply closedness.